# Arduino IDE error msgs

Tags: ide, null, serial-port, arduino, sudo

A few days ago everything was working Ok but now I have 2 errors with Arduino:

1. IDE error when I open a random sketch. And then that window dies and cant even close it. It says

   **Thread -l ... Java.Lang.NullPointerException**

   Heres a screenshot:
   [image]

[image]

2. Cant upload my code to the board unless I ran arduino with sudo. (I get "cant find ttyACM0"  for example) I didnt need this two days ago. Is there any way I could make it go back to normal?

Thanks! hope someone can help me.

**EDIT:**

I just downloaded version 1.0.4 and problem #1 is gone. But #2 and #3 still there... And i noticed that when I dont run arduino with sudo, problem #3 is gone. BUt i need sudo to upload my code to the board.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

I would save your sketches (copy them to a new location, or thumb drive) and either reinstall the arduino software or see if an update is available. Reinstalling/updating should fix it.

Comment: I just downloaded version 1.0.4 and problem #1 is gone. But #2 and #3 still there... And i noticed that when I dont run arduino with sudo, problem #3 is gone. BUt i need sudo to upload my code to the board. @Jordan

Comment: In ubuntu go into the software manager and install all available software updates. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First plug in your Arduino and then on the command line

```
ls /dev/tty*
```

To see what devices you have on your system.  Check your Arduino IDE's `Tools/Serial Port` menu: you should have something there. If there is more than one thing, try both.

YOu might also need to change the permissions on the serial port mapped to your Arduino:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Where `ttyACM0` is the name of your device. Newer versions of Arduino IDE achieve the same effect (though more securely) by adding the current user to the `dialout` group.

Comment: didn't work :(  When trying to upload: Error Opening serial port /dev/ttyACM0 (and my arduino is on ttyACM0) Here is the full error I get when not using sudo to upload http://pastebin.com/4MCQNGDP

Comment: Can you paste the results of `ls -lA /dev/ttyACM0` somewhere?

Comment: yep, here http://pastebin.com/R1MqZ3vY. Sorry about the delay, I couldn't do it before.

Comment: Sorry, just to check, you tried 1. plug in Ardiono 2. `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0` 3. Running Arduino IDE w/o removing the Arduino, yes?  Also try this `sudo usermod -a -G dialout yourUserName`, just to be sure.  And then double check that Arduino IDE runs under your username (`ps xau | grep arduino`).

Comment: no improvements :( Yes I did follow those steps. and about the second part, I think it is runnning under my username : http://pastebin.com/cky0WL6m

Comment: Can you check to make sure your serial.download_rate is set to 19200 and serial.debug_rate is set to 9600 in the `~/.arduino/preferences.txt`?

Comment: I couldnt find serial.download_rate but debug_rate is 9600. I tried adding a line for download_rate but nothing happened , serial.port=COM1
serial.databits=8
serial.stopbits=1
serial.parity=N
serial.debug_rate=9600

Comment: Try the `serial.download_rate` to `9600` and to `19200`. Your serial.port should be `/dev/ttyACM0`. Parity, databits, and stop bits look good.  Make sure you edit `~/.arduino/preferences.txt` while Arduino IDE isn't running.